# slmgr.vbs supress dialog

Tags: windows, batch-file, activation

We use a batch file with the following content to activate our windows domain computer after imaging:

```
slmgr.vbs -ipk XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
slmgr -ato
```

This works well, but there is a problem: after each command a dialog box appears and the file does not continue until you closed it.

Is there a way to supress the dialog boxes? (on success, not on error). A way so that at least both commands are executed without user intervention would be fine too (it gets boring to walk past 50+ computer and pressing enter on each of them)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try 'start slmgr -ato' in your batch file

Answer (score 10):

Calling via cscript also works

```
cscript C:\Windows\System32\slmgr.vbs /ato
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41423512/batch-file-i-want-to-supress-the-windows-script-host-pop-ups

add '//b' to your command.  That suppresses the popup.

e.g.

```
slmgr.vbs //b -ipk XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
```

Comment: I like Ritch Melton's solution better because the information is printed to the standard output.

Answer (score -1):

+1 for the "cscript ..." variant which provides useful ERRORLEVEL on command execution whereas the "add '//b'" variant does not give any ERRORLEVEL on exit.

Kind regards
Chris

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/563912)